# Efficient way to check if thousands records exist in a million records

Tags: salesforce

I have an external excel file with about 15K records of a specific object.

I want to check if those records are present in all the records of an object I have in salesforce.

Doing it with Excel is pretty slow and doesn't fit well as I have a bit more than 1 million records.

I have done something with Visualforce and apex, uploading the file, reading each line and checking if records exist.
While this works, I only can upload about 5K contacts to a visualforce page(limited upload size).

I would like to know if I can do it with an other solution easily ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software named "TALEND"
You can download both excel files and then create a job in talend to compare these 2 files

Cordially